# Trying to insert node in a singly linked list after a certain position but it inserts it before

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

Trying to insert a  node in a linked list after a certain position but it inserts it before.
Tried modifying it and it still adds it before or just drops the  rest of the linked list

```
Destination *insertAfter(Destination *head, Destination *node, char *key)
{
    Destination *ptr;
    Destination *previous = NULL;
    Destination *newNode = (Destination*)malloc(sizeof(Destination));
    if(head == NULL)
    {
         return node;
    }
    for(ptr =head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr-> next)
    {
       if(strcmp(ptr->code, key) == 0)
       {
          node->next = ptr;

        if(previous != NULL)
          {
            previous->next = node;
            return head;
          }
        else
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
    previous = ptr;
   }
  previous->next = node;
  return head;

}
```

Comment: @HenriPrudhomme so essentially user enters a string and it searches through the linked list and inputs it after the string they entered

Comment: I've got the answer, give me 15 mins to type it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost have it. the problem you are having is that once you find a string match, your code loses track of the pointer to the next node.

```
Destination *insertAfter(Destination *head, Destination *node, char *key)
{
    Destination *matchNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        for(matchNode = head; matchNode != NULL; matchNode = matchNode->next)
        {
            //check for match
            if(strcomp(matchNode->code, key) == 0)
            {
                //Set remaining list to what follows the inserted node
                node->next = matchNode->next;

                //Set new node as next node to front half of list
                matchNode->next = node;
            }
        }
    }
    return *head;
}
```

I didn't add any extra safety checks beyond what you provided, but you will need to also check that head and node have been allocated.

I hope this helps a little bit. I can't test if this compiles with you code, so if you get anything out of this, you need to know that you have to save the end of the list before you assign the match index to the node to be inserted and ONLY then can you append the end of the list to the node you inserting.

If this doesn't work out, let me know.